# Cloning Phoenix Hbase table snapshot from a HDP cluster to CDP Cluster not working properly

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdp, cdp

I am having a HDP hadoop cluster. I took snapshot of phoenix table from this cluster & I cloned that table to a CDP cluster. Hbase table was  created from the snapshot & the hfiles are imported  to the table's data directory . While selecting the table from phoenix shell, empty data it is showing. If I do a scan operation from `hbase shell` data is displaying (encoded). Is there any workaround for this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Did you clone Phoenix `SYSTEM` tables as well?

Comment: you are probably running into column encoding issue when migrating a table from 2.x.x version to CDP that has phoenix 5. Try setting COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES=0 for the phoenix table that you copied from HDP cluster.

Comment: @mazaneicha no I didn't cloned that

Comment: @AnilGupta For the existing table data will it work or is it for new table & data ?

Comment: When you copy an existing table in hdp 2.x.x to CDP cluster that has phoenix 5 and up then you need to set COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES=0.
If you are creating a new table in CDP cluster that is not restored from a snapshot from hdp cluster then you dont need to set COLUMN_ENCODED_BYTES=0.